# How do I distribute MonoGame games in Windows?

Tags: monogame, publishing, visual-studio, openal

I'm using VS2013 and MonoGame to create a simple game. The things is I can't make it run on others PCs.

- I've tried to copy Content to the Release folder using the "always copy" option in VS2013;
- I've tried to add the OpenAL and wrap_oal DLLs to the Release folder too but it is not working;
- I've tried to Publish the game using this functionality of VS2013 but no success neither.

Am I forgetting something?

Edit: I'm using the OpenGL template (I've tried the DirectX but had the same problem).

Comment: why are you not using directX template in a windows game made with monogame ? are you using opengl ?

Comment: @Shiro I'm using OpenGL (I've tried DX before too, but I ran in the same problem)

Comment: In your DirectX monogame project, you have Monogame.Framework reference added by default. Do you have ["copy local = true"](http://i.gyazo.com/084a9cbaa66928f28a29e301f715f7e5.png) ? Monogame requires DirectX installed and .net framework 4.0 (which is an important update on windows 7, and its already pre-installed in windows 8) You don't want to be using opengl, for any reason in a windows game made with monogame

Comment: @Shiro Thanks! I'll check into that and tell you if it works.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "can't make it run"? What does it do when you try to run it? Does the computer explode violently when you try it, or does it rather quietly melt into a puddle of goo? What does your favorite search engine say when you enter color, smell and consistency of said goo?

Comment: @Philipp, let's say it gently explodes without goo dropping. It just crashes while starting up. That is why I made an account in this goo analysis website and wrote this question.

Comment: OK, so "it just crashes". What exactly does "it just crashes" mean? Is there any error message of some kind? People can not help you when you don't provide any information about the symptoms of your problem?

Comment: you can use `try { Game1 g = new Game1(); } catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }` and see the full error if you don't see any errors, however how did the `directx` project go ? do you still get errors ?

Comment: @Shiro Thanks! I am testing my releases on a different pc with Win7. This pc has .NET 4.5 installed. It turns out the target machine didn't have an updated DX. One extra DLL in the application folder resolved the issue. I copied together _xinput1_3.dll_ and it worked.